# can not retrieve model correctly through ScanStreamTransformer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to retrieve an `ItemModel` class from my repository using streams implementing the `BLoC` logic in Flutter.

The problem is that the `ItemModel` is found but not retrieved . Therefore there is another loop triggered and tries to return a different Object, which is not retrieve on the Widgets.

Sample output:

```
I/flutter ( 4520): trying to get 25314126 from cache
I/flutter ( 4520): 25314126 in transformer
I/flutter ( 4520): 25314126 found !! returning: {id: 25314126, type: story, by: xucheng, time: 1607172267, text: , parent: null, kids: [25314805,25314781,25314684,25314664], dead: 0, deleted: 0, url: https://bitbashing.io/std-visit.html, score: 24, title: std::visit is everything wrong with modern C++ (2017), descendants: 4}
I/flutter ( 4520): ----------item to find: 25314126 and found: Instance of 'ItemModel'
I/flutter ( 4520): returned item Instance of 'ItemModel'
```

Here the correct Object is found and retrieved but not received on the UI and therefore there is another search right away:

```
I/flutter ( 4520): trying to get 25314805 from cache
I/flutter ( 4520): 25314805 found !! returning: {id: 25314805, type: comment, by: vasama, time: 1607178963, text: We got here because adding library features is a lot easier and less risky than adding language features. Work on pattern matching [1] is ongoing, but the bar for entry for a language feature is much higher and as such takes a longer time.<p>1. <a href="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;wg21.link&#x2F;p1371" rel="nofollow">http:&#x2F;&#x2F;wg21.link&#x2F;p1371</a>, parent: 25314126, kids: [], dead: 0, deleted: 0, url: null, score: null, title: null, descendants: 0}
I/flutter ( 4520): ----------item to find: 25314805 and found: Instance of 'ItemModel'
I/flutter ( 4520): returned item Instance of 'ItemModel'
```

Which is not the Object I'm trying to retrieve!!!

---

### There is always 'Loading 1' String shown

Here is my main `Widget`

```
class NewsDetail extends StatelessWidget{
  final int itemId;

   NewsDetail({ this.itemId}) ;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = CommentsProvider.of(context);


    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Detail'),
      ),
      body: buildBody(bloc),

    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(CommentsBloc bloc){
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.itemWithComments,
        builder:
            (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<int,Future<ItemModel>>> snapshot){

          if (!snapshot.hasData){
            return Text('Loading 1');
          }

          final itemFuture = snapshot.data[itemId];

          return FutureBuilder(
              future: itemFuture,
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> itemSnapshot){


                if(!itemSnapshot.hasData){
                  return Text('Loading 2');
                }

                return buildTitle(itemSnapshot.data);
              }
          );

        },);
  }
```

which indicates that is something wrong with the `stream: bloc.itemWithComments,`

Here is my BLOC class:

```
class CommentsBloc{
  final _repository = Repository();
  final _commentsFetcher = PublishSubject<int>();
  final _commentsOutput = BehaviorSubject<Map<int,Future<ItemModel>>>();

  //Streams
  get itemWithComments =>  _commentsOutput.stream;

  //Sink
  Function(int) get fetchItemWithComments => _commentsFetcher.sink.add;

  CommentsBloc(){
    _commentsFetcher.stream.transform(_commentsTransformer()).pipe(_commentsOutput);
  }

  _commentsTransformer (){
    return ScanStreamTransformer(
        (cache,int id,index){
          cache[id] = _repository.fetchItem(id);
          print('$id in transformer');
          cache[id].then((ItemModel item){
            item.kids.forEach((kidId)=>fetchItemWithComments(kidId));

          });
        },
      <int,Future<ItemModel>>{},
    );
  }


  dispose(){
    _commentsFetcher.close();
    _commentsOutput.close();
  }

}
```

And here is how i fetch items in my `Repository` class

```
 List<Source> sources = <Source>[
    newsDbProvider,
    NewsApiProvider(),
  ];
  List<Cache> caches = <Cache>[
   newsDbProvider,
  ];

Future<ItemModel> fetchItem(int id) async{

    ItemModel item;
    var source;

    for(source in sources) {
        item = await source.fetchItem(id);
        print('----------item to find: $id and found: ${item}');
        if(item!=null){
         break;
        }
      }

    for(var cache in caches) {
      if(cache!=source) {
        cache.addItem(item);
      }
    }

    print('returned item ${item}');

    return item;

  }
```

> Even though there is an Instance returned every time why is the `snapshot.hasData` **false**?

Also please note that the widget gets invoked just **once** with the **correct id** by using `onTap` method. What have i completely missed?

Answer (score 1):

Even though i used the `fetchItemWithComments` to sink the items, I still had to add a return statement in the `ScanStreamTransformer`

```dart
_commentsTransformer (){
    return  ScanStreamTransformer<int,Map<int,Future<ItemModel>>>(
        (Map<int,Future<ItemModel>>cache,int id,index){
          print(index);
          cache[id] = _repository.fetchItem(id);
          cache[id].then((ItemModel item){
            item.kids.forEach(  (kidId)   =>   fetchItemWithComments(kidId)  );
          });
          return cache; //was missing this
        },
      <int,Future<ItemModel>>{},
    );
  }
```

This had been bugging me for days, I went over everything and couldn't find anything so if you are using a `ScanStreamTransformer` class

> Always have a `return` statement